# Should I pay to have an IP address removed from UCEPROTECT's backlist?

Tags: ip-address, blacklist

I'm working with a group that switched their TLD a year ago. I checked their old and new IP's on MXToolbox. The last search showed their old IP address was blacklisted by UCEPROTECT L3.

I looked further and they noted it was because of a DO Droplet.
I'm decent at working with groups like Spamhaus. This site didn't provide much info, but did say I could get the blacklist removed if I pay for it.

Should I pay to have this IP address removed from UCEPROTECT?

Comment: The [L3](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/blacklist/uceprotectl3) classification means the entire IP address range was blacklisted, so that's quite possibly not the fault of the website you're working with. As indicated in the above link, it will be delisted automatically after a period of time. Also, if it's only an old IP, I wouldn't worry about it since just the new IP would be checked for in blacklist databases.

Comment: This is good to know thanks!